# Setting am/pm time on lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu

How do I get the time on Lubuntu into an am/pm format instead of the 24-hour clock?  I have tried the Time/Date, but that hasn't worked.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to AskUbuntu. Do you mind telling us where exactly do you want to see that time's format? If you wish to use it in a terminal you can drop `date +%r` which will return the time in the next format:

[image]

More information in the date's man page at: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/date.1.html

If you wish to change panel's time format, take a look at this [LUbuntu's install/tweak guide](http://linuxftw.weebly.com/lubuntu-1110-installation-guide.html), specially on "**Step #09**" which reads the next:

### **Step #09: Customize The Clock (Show Date and Time AM/PM)**

> By default, Lubuntu does not show the date in the panel and only shows
>   24-hour time. This is annoying especially since you take the time to
>   choose your timezone during the installation. If you're in the USA
>   like me, you can have the Lubuntu panel display the proper time format
>   with a little tweak.
>
> Right click on the clock and select "Digital Clock Settings" and
>   change the Clock Format and Tooltip Format's to the following:

```
Clock Format: %m/%d/%y %I:%M
Tooltip Format: %A %x
```

[image]

But if you wish to set the time format in a different place please let us know by editing your question, after which this answer can be edited or deleted.

Thank you and Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much--I have succeeded in changing the time/date.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the clock on your panel in lubuntu  you may be interseted in [their wiki about it](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/CustomizingTheClock). Not everyone are familiar with strftime format but there are some examples in the wiki of some common ones. For more advanced use you should look at [the strftime man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) or use the simple [strftime format string creator](http://www.foragoodstrftime.com/) they linked to in the wiki.

Comment: Thank you so very much--I have set the date/time as I had wanted to.

Comment: The link [Customizing the Clock](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LXDE-lubuntu/Documentation/CustomizingTheClock) is more to the point because it shows the formatting characters and their meaning with examples.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the clock and left click 'Configure "World Clock"' and then tick 'Use 12-hour format'