# How to edit my Lubuntu 14.10 digital clock settings?

Tags: lubuntu, .desktop, time

I right clicked on the below situated task bar to find out digital clock settings. I got digital clock settings from there.

But, it looks unfamiliar than that of Ubuntu 14.04. And I don't know how to edit the digital clock settings in Lubuntu 14.10. Please do help me to resolve this problem. Can I get any digital clock App for Lubuntu 14.10?

It doesn't show AM/PM after the time, Why? How can I reset that from 24 hour format to 12 hour format?

Comment: A similar question was asked https://askubuntu.com/q/324105/67558

Answer (score 3):

In order to show AM/PM you have to change the clock format field in the digital clock settings from `%R` to `%I:%M %p`

You can read more about all the possible configuration options in the official documentation - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/CustomizingTheClock